# Text cut off after the character  in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, visual-editor, encoding

I use the latest version of wordpress (v3.9.2, Taiwan Chinese Traditional), and found it can not display this Chinese word , but other Chinese words can be displayed normally.

I just use this word on a post, and all the content after it is lost (became blank, this word disappeared too), after I saved the post to draft. What should I do?

Comment: I was able to have that word in post content by switching to text editor for post content (no TinyMCE) and typing `&#172486;` then publishing post while text editor is active. I can confirm that switching to TinyMCE and then update post the content is lost.

Comment: yes, i can paste the word from ms-word, and can see it; but, after save the post, it disappeared!

Comment: update: i found an interesting thing: i tested with my blog on the Wordpress.com, and found it's all ok!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a limitation of JavaScript.  is [U+2A1C6 in Unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2a1c6/index.htm), and codepoints above U+FFFF (which need four bytes) are coded via [UTF-16 surrogates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885879/javascript-and-string-manipulation-w-utf-16-surrogate-pairs). And that … sucks.

The canonical bug for that in WordPress is [#13590 Inserting a 4-byte UTF-8 character truncates data](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13590). It was closed as *maybe later*, because fixing it would require a change in the database encoding that [WordPress’ current schema just cannot handle](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21212#comment:10).

You could try the plugin [TinyMCE Chinese Convert](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-chinese-convert/) and switch to Simplified Chinese to get around that.

Comment: hmm, the problem just as you say, but, are there any other solutions? like: 1) modify the config to let it support displaying natively? 2) get this word from other url? 3) save and display it using raw data, no cut off? '' just has no simplified chinese version, only another form: '鸀' with different pronunciation!

Comment: @kenmux I am not aware of a better solution. Let’s wait, maybe someone else has a better idea.